# read_graphviz() in Boost::Graph, pass to constructor

Tags: c++, boost, graph

I have used a python library to generate the following GraphViz .dot file.

http://pastebin.com/mL7ck9Zp

I want to now read it into C++'s Boost::Graph so I can use Boost::Graph's library algorithms on it.

However, I need to do some preprocessing. In particular, I want to create a bundled property with a string constructor and have read_graphviz() pass the string in the label field in the dot file into the string constructor.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: The constructor thing cannot be granted. The algorithm specifically requires the properties to be default constructible (hey, the docs not _that_ bad :)). _(You might parse into a temp graph, and build a clone from that in your preferred graph type)_

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First thing to realize is that Boost documentation samples *almost* always refer to/are generated from the actual samples: [libs/graph/example/read_graphviz.cpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/example/read_graphviz.cpp)

Second thing to realize is that BGL is highly generic. Highly. And it achieves much of this genericity on the concepts of [Boost Property Maps](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/property_map/doc/property_map.html).

Finally, observe that parsing from "free-form" (at least dynamically/untyped text form) into some kind of *generic [MutableGraph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/MutableGraph.html) model* is pushing the limits.

This explains how you would have to read important parts of the documentation under [the docs for property_map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/property_map/doc/dynamic_property_map.html#fred-s-info-revisited).

Anyhow, since indeed [the sample](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/example/read_graphviz.cpp) seems a bit dated, allow me to demonstrate:

1. Include the implementation of the parser into one translation unit:

   ```
   #include <libs/graph/src/read_graphviz_new.cpp>
   ```

   This way BGL remains a header-only library.
2. Prefer bundled properties these days:

   ```
   struct Vertex {
       std::string name, label, shape;
   };

   struct Edge {
       std::string label;
       double weight; // perhaps you need this later as well, just an example
   };

   typedef property<graph_name_t, std::string> graph_p;
   typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, directedS, Vertex, Edge, graph_p> graph_t;
   ```

   We will be filling `label`, `shape`, `name` for vertices and edges.
3. The dynamic property maps are where the magic happens:

   ```
   dynamic_properties dp/*(ignore_other_properties)*/;
   ```

   This class provides type-erased access to a variety of underlying [property maps](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/property_map/doc/property_map.html) identified by `(name, typeid(key_type))`.

   This means you can register the bundled properties, and map them to the graphviz attribute names:

   ```
   int main() {
       // Construct an empty graph and prepare the dynamic_property_maps.
       graph_t graph(0);

       dynamic_properties dp(ignore_other_properties);
       dp.property("node_id", get(&Vertex::name,  graph));
       dp.property("label",   get(&Vertex::label, graph));
       dp.property("shape",   get(&Vertex::shape, graph));
       dp.property("label",   get(&Edge::label,   graph));
   ```

   > That's really all there is to it. *(Read up on the [magic of Bundled Properties](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html), found via the [page for the `adjacency_list` template](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html)).*

   Though we don't need it, let's throw the graph property in the mix too (as in the documentation sample):

   ```
       // Use ref_property_map to turn a graph property into a property map
       boost::ref_property_map<graph_t *, std::string> gname(get_property(graph, graph_name));
       dp.property("name",    gname);
   ```
4. Now all that's left is reading the graph.

   Well. Okay then. And let's write it back out too, but with a new graph name, then:

   ```
   std::ifstream dot("input.dot");

   if (read_graphviz(dot, graph, dp/*, "node_id"*/)) {
       std::cout << "Graph name: '" << get_property(graph, graph_name) << "'\n";
       get_property(graph, graph_name) = "Let's give it a name";
       write_graphviz_dp(std::cout, graph, dp/*, "node_id"*/);
   }
   ```
5. Don't forget to link to Boost Regex

### Full Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ee0f4f263d51caa)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/dynamic_property_map.hpp>
#include <libs/graph/src/read_graphviz_new.cpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>

using namespace boost;

struct Vertex {
    std::string name, label, shape;
};

struct Edge {
    std::string label;
    double weight; // perhaps you need this later as well, just an example
};

typedef property<graph_name_t, std::string> graph_p;
typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, directedS, Vertex, Edge, graph_p> graph_t;

int main() {
    // Construct an empty graph and prepare the dynamic_property_maps.
    graph_t graph(0);

    dynamic_properties dp/*(ignore_other_properties)*/;
    dp.property("node_id", get(&Vertex::name,  graph));
    dp.property("label",   get(&Vertex::label, graph));
    dp.property("shape",   get(&Vertex::shape, graph));
    dp.property("label",   get(&Edge::label,   graph));

    // Use ref_property_map to turn a graph property into a property map
    boost::ref_property_map<graph_t *, std::string> gname(get_property(graph, graph_name));
    dp.property("name",    gname);

    std::ifstream dot("input.dot");

    if (read_graphviz(dot, graph, dp/*, "node_id"*/)) {
        std::cout << "Graph name: '" << get_property(graph, graph_name) << "'\n";
        get_property(graph, graph_name) = "Let's give it a name";
        write_graphviz_dp(std::cout, graph, dp/*, "node_id"*/);
    }
}
```

Prints (note the empty name before, and the updated graph name attribute, after):

```
Graph name: ''
digraph G {
name="Let's give it a name";
n0 [label="A9\n", shape=box];
n1 [label="- [0.48%,19.42%]", shape=ellipse];
n11 [label="+ [0%,0%]", shape=ellipse];
n12 [label="- [0%,0.75%]", shape=ellipse];
n13 [label="+ [0.03%,1.33%]", shape=ellipse];
n14 [label="- [0%,0.75%]", shape=ellipse];
n15 [label="+ [0%,0%]", shape=ellipse];
n16 [label="+ [0%,0%]", shape=ellipse];
n17 [label="A14\n", shape=box];
n18 [label="+ [0.03%,2.51%]", shape=ellipse];
n19 [label="A15\n", shape=box];
n2 [label="A15\n", shape=box];
n20 [label="A6\n", shape=box];
n21 [label="A2\n", shape=box];
n22 [label="- [0%,1.11%]", shape=ellipse];
n23 [label="+ [0%,1%]", shape=ellipse];
n25 [label="- [0%,2.18%]", shape=ellipse];
n26 [label="+ [0%,1.79%]", shape=ellipse];
n27 [label="- [0%,1%]", shape=ellipse];
n28 [label="- [0%,0%]", shape=ellipse];
n29 [label="- [0%,0%]", shape=ellipse];
n3 [label="A11\n", shape=box];
n30 [label="- [0%,0%]", shape=ellipse];
n31 [label="- [0%,0%]", shape=ellipse];
n32 [label="- [0%,1%]", shape=ellipse];
n33 [label="A13\n", shape=box];
n34 [label="+ [0%,1%]", shape=ellipse];
n35 [label="- [0%,0%]", shape=ellipse];
n36 [label="- [0.01%,1.21%]", shape=ellipse];
n38 [label="A12\n", shape=box];
n39 [label="- [0%,1%]", shape=ellipse];
n4 [label="A4\n", shape=box];
n40 [label="+ [0%,1.17%]", shape=ellipse];
n42 [label="- [0%,0%]", shape=ellipse];
n43 [label="A12\n", shape=box];
n44 [label="+ [0%,1.11%]", shape=ellipse];
n45 [label="- [0%,1%]", shape=ellipse];
n47 [label="- [0%,0%]", shape=ellipse];
n49 [label="+ [0%,1.17%]", shape=ellipse];
n5 [label="+ [0%,0%]", shape=ellipse];
n52 [label="+ [0%,0.75%]", shape=ellipse];
n54 [label="A13\n", shape=box];
n55 [label="A14\n", shape=box];
n56 [label="- [0.03%,2.5%]", shape=ellipse];
n57 [label="+ [0.01%,2.27%]", shape=ellipse];
n59 [label="- [0%,0%]", shape=ellipse];
n6 [label="A7\n", shape=box];
n60 [label="+ [0%,1%]", shape=ellipse];
n63 [label="A15\n", shape=box];
n64 [label="+ [0.05%,1.34%]", shape=ellipse];
n65 [label="A15\n", shape=box];
n66 [label="- [0%,1%]", shape=ellipse];
n67 [label="+ [0.02%,2.44%]", shape=ellipse];
n7 [label="A14\n", shape=box];
n71 [label="+ [0.21%,3.83%]", shape=ellipse];
n8 [label="+ [0%,1.57%]", shape=ellipse];
n9 [label="- [0.01%,1.22%]", shape=ellipse];
n0->n1  [label=f];
n0->n2  [label=t];
n17->n18  [label="<=110"];
n17->n19  [label=">110"];
n19->n20  [label="<=8"];
n19->n49  [label=">8"];
n2->n3  [label="<=228"];
n2->n71  [label=">228"];
n20->n21  [label=aa];
n20->n25  [label=c];
n20->n26  [label=cc];
n20->n27  [label=d];
n20->n28  [label=e];
n20->n29  [label=ff];
n20->n30  [label=i];
n20->n31  [label=j];
n20->n32  [label=k];
n20->n33  [label=m];
n20->n38  [label=q];
n20->n42  [label=r];
n20->n43  [label=w];
n20->n47  [label=x];
n21->n22  [label="<=41"];
n21->n23  [label=">41"];
n3->n4  [label="<=3"];
n3->n63  [label=">3"];
n33->n34  [label=g];
n33->n35  [label=p];
n33->n36  [label=s];
n38->n39  [label=f];
n38->n40  [label=t];
n4->n5  [label=l];
n4->n6  [label=u];
n4->n54  [label=y];
n43->n44  [label=f];
n43->n45  [label=t];
n54->n55  [label=g];
n54->n59  [label=p];
n54->n60  [label=s];
n55->n56  [label="<=204"];
n55->n57  [label=">204"];
n6->n7  [label=bb];
n6->n11  [label=dd];
n6->n12  [label=ff];
n6->n13  [label=h];
n6->n14  [label=j];
n6->n15  [label=n];
n6->n16  [label=o];
n6->n17  [label=v];
n6->n52  [label=z];
n63->n64  [label="<=4"];
n63->n65  [label=">4"];
n65->n66  [label="<=5"];
n65->n67  [label=">5"];
n7->n8  [label="<=164"];
n7->n9  [label=">164"];
}
```

Comment: Wow! Let me remove the comment about the documentation. I'm not a programmer and it was frustrating trying to get this to work.

Comment: @avak Oh, I do realize I have the "unfair" advantage of having read through these docs many a time before (even so, I found it worth noting that I found the docs for property bundles only through the page for `adjacency_list`, e.g.). Cheers

Comment: I try this example in a similar graph but when I want to read the dot file I get this error: `Attempt to put a value into a const property map`, anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Bruce I don't have my crystal ball polished, but a good guess is when your map doesn't model an [LvaluePropertyMap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/property_map/doc/LvaluePropertyMap.html) where one is required. Feel free to post a question if you can't make it work

Comment: @sehe Ahh, I know what was the problem, I was using: `vertex_index` as `node_id` `dp.property ("node_id", get (boost::vertex_index, graph));` the put method of propertymap couldn't put vertex_index in the property map, by changinh it to another property such as string it works.

Comment: @Bruce Thanks for the comment, I was having the same issue. I am using a std::string label in my bundled Vertex to workaround about this, as suggested. It works, but I would like to avoid it (having an unused data member, just to be able to read a graph). Is there another way to avoid that error?

Comment: @phcerdan You can fake it by modelling the LValuePropertyMap concept manually and feeding it (you may make it so the `put` operation throws?).

Comment: @phcerdan Ah. Another day where google tells me I've answered a very similar question before https://stackoverflow.com/a/27238425/85371 (it looks like you don't even have to bother with the missing `put` operation: it's not an issue if the code doesn't use that part of the concept interface)