# Accessing BGL GraphProperty

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I am trying to access the graph label for a *dot(graphviz)* formatted input file using the Boost Graph Library. Below is the typedef for the graph type:

```
struct DotVertex {
  std::string label;
};

struct DotEdge {
  std::string label;
};

struct DotGraph {
  std::string label;
};

typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS,
                              DotVertex, DotEdge, DotGraph> graph_t;
```

And this is how I assign the dynamic properties:

```
  graph_t graphviz;

  boost::dynamic_properties dp(boost::ignore_other_properties);

  dp.property("label",       boost::get(&DotGraph::label,          graphviz));
  dp.property("label",       boost::get(&DotVertex::label,         graphviz));
  dp.property("label",       boost::get(&DotEdge::label,           graphviz));
  std::ifstream ifs("sample.dot");
  bool status = boost::read_graphviz(ifs, graphviz, dp);
```

The compiler complains about the assignment for the *DotGraph::label* with the error message:

```
read_graph.cc:25:30: error: no matching function for call to 'get'   dp.property("label",       boost::get(&DotGraph::label,          graphviz));
```

Can someone point out what is the convenient way to read the graph label in this case? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to map the graph property using as found in step 3 of [read_graphviz() in Boost::Graph, pass to constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29496182/read-graphviz-in-boostgraph-pass-to-constructor):

```
  boost::ref_property_map<graph_t *, std::string> dg_label(get_property(graphviz, &DotGraph::label));
  dp.property("label",       dg_label);
```

And then can access the label by:

```
 std::cout<<get_property(graphviz, &DotGraph::label)<<std::endl;
```

Comment: I had forgotten about this, though I wrote the answer linked to :)