# How to read GraphML file to Boost Graph with custom Vertex Property?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph, graphml

I am trying to create a boost graph of robot joint configuration space. For that I am using custom VertexProperty.

```
struct VertexProperties {
    std::vector<double> joint_angles;
    
    VertexProperties() : joint_angles(3){}
    
};
```

I have saved the graph using write_graphML with below implementation

````
std::string BoostGraph::vertexJointAngles(Vertex& v){
   
    std::ostringstream sstream;
    std::vector<double> jointAngles(graph[v].joint_angles);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < jointAngles.size(); i++){
                 sstream  << jointAngles[i];
                 if(i != jointAngles.size()-1) sstream << ',';
        }

    return sstream.str();
}


```
void BoostGraph::printGraphML(std::ostream &out){

    boost::function_property_map<std::function<std::string(Vertex)>, Vertex> jointAngles([this](Vertex v)
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            return vertexJointAngles(v);
                                                                                        });

                                                                                      });   
    boost::dynamic_properties dp;

    dp.property("Joint_Angles", jointAngles);
    dp.property("edge_weight", boost::get(&EdgeProperties::weight, graph));
    
    boost::write_graphml(out, graph, dp);
}
````

Now I need to read the graph again in another BoostGraph class instance for query and A* search. How can I convert the joint angles saved as string in graphml to vertex property?

I tried the below implementation ( I am just starting in Boost) but its not working.

```
std::vector<double> BoostGraph::readJointAngles(std::string joint_angle_string){
    std::stringstream ss;

    ss << joint_angle_string;

    std::vector<double> joint_angle;
    double number;
    while (ss >> number)
        joint_angle.push_back(number);

    return joint_angle;
}

void BoostGraph::readGraphGraphML(std::istream& file){
    boost::dynamic_properties dp;

    boost::function_property_map<std::function<std::vector<double>(std::string)>, Vertex> jointAngles([this](std::string v)
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            return readJointAngles(v);
                                                                                        });
    dp.property("Joint_Angles", jointAngles );                                                                                   
    dp.property("edge_weight", boost::get(&EdgeProperties::weight, graph));
    boost::read_graphml(file, graph, dp);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good starting point there. Nice job.

Therefore I'm going to jump immediately to the pain point:

Writable property maps have to return something that *models lvalue semantics*. Your `readJointAngles` assumes a "procedural" conversion task instead. That's not a property map.

My first thought is to stay close to the concept of the property map by combining the read and write into a proxy class. The proxy class can be `VertexProperties` itself, but as I can imagine `VertexProperties` having multiple members with similar requirements, let me do the "pure" thing and have it separate here:

```
struct JointAngleWrapper {
    std::vector<double>& _ref;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, JointAngleWrapper wrapper) {
        for (auto sep = ""; auto el : wrapper._ref)
            os << std::exchange(sep, ",") << el;
        return os;
    }
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, JointAngleWrapper wrapper) {
        std::vector<double> tmp;

        while (is >> tmp.emplace_back())
            if (char comma{}; !(is >> comma) || comma != ',')
                break;

        wrapper._ref = std::move(tmp);

        is.clear();
        return is;
    }
};
```

Now you can replace the function property-map:

```
    auto jointAngles = boost::make_function_property_map<Vertex>(
        [ja = get(&VertexProperties::joint_angles, graph)](Vertex v) {
            return JointAngleWrapper{ja[v]};
        });
    dp.property("Joint_Angles", jointAngles);
```

And the output will still be identical. Actually, we have a more light-weight property map abstraction that fits the bill even more elegantly:

```
    auto jointAngles = make_transform_value_property_map(
        [](std::vector<double>& ja) { return JointAngleWrapper{ja}; },
        get(&VertexProperties::joint_angles, graph));
```

### A Road Bump

However, `function_property_map` is still not an lvalue-property map. That's sad.

Turns out I forgot about this snag. I've written about this rather central issue with `read_graphml` (or with `dynamic_properties`, really) before:

- [Boost::Graph: how to import graphviz with custom Vertex class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68561134/boostgraph-how-to-import-graphviz-with-custom-vertex-class/68578943#68578943) (which links to other relevant answers)

The approach I took there was to create my own [`ReadWritePropertyMap`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/property_map/doc/ReadWritePropertyMap.html). Which is sensible, given that it essentially merges into what we already have above (`JointAngleWrapper`).

```
template <typename Prop> struct JA {
    Prop inner;
    JA(Prop map) : inner(map) { }

    // traits
    using value_type = std::string;
    using reference  = std::string;
    using key_type   = typename boost::property_traits<Prop>::key_type;
    using category   = boost::read_write_property_map_tag;

    friend std::string get(JA map, key_type const& key) {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        for (auto sep = ""; auto el : get(map.inner, key))
            oss << std::exchange(sep, ",") << el;
        return oss.str();
    }
    friend void put(JA map, key_type const& key, value_type const& value) {
        auto& v = get(map.inner, key);
        v.clear();

        std::istringstream iss(value);
        while (iss >> v.emplace_back())
            if (char comma{}; !(iss >> comma) || comma != ',')
                break;
    }
};
```

Now you can use it with success:

```
struct BoostGraph {
    Graph graph;

    auto properties() {
        boost::dynamic_properties dp;
        dp.property("Joint_Angles", JA{get(&VertexProperties::joint_angles, graph)});
        dp.property("edge_weight", get(&EdgeProperties::weight, graph));
        return dp;
    }

    void printGraphML(std::ostream& out) {
        write_graphml(out, graph, properties());
    }

    void readGraphGraphML(std::istream& file) {
        auto dp = properties();
        read_graphml(file, graph, dp);
    }
};
```

Which successfully roundtrips a "random" graph:

```
#include <boost/graph/random.hpp>
#include <random>

int main() {
    std::stringstream file; // fake file in memory
    {
        BoostGraph g;
        std::mt19937 prng{42};
        generate_random_graph(g.graph, 5, 2, prng);

        for (auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g.graph)))
            for (auto& angle : g.graph[v].joint_angles)
                angle = std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(-M_PI, +M_PI)(prng);

        g.printGraphML(file);
    }

    {
        BoostGraph roundtrip;
        roundtrip.readGraphGraphML(file);
        roundtrip.printGraphML(std::cout);
    }
}
```

Prints

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">
  <key id="key0" for="node" attr.name="Joint_Angles" attr.type="string" />
  <key id="key1" for="edge" attr.name="edge_weight" attr.type="double" />
  <graph id="G" edgedefault="directed" parse.nodeids="free" parse.edgeids="canonical" parse.order="nodesfirst">
    <node id="n0">
      <data key="key0">1.75735,0.608528,-0.340343</data>
    </node>
    <node id="n1">
      <data key="key0">-2.51343,-0.256047,-1.04484</data>
    </node>
    <node id="n2">
      <data key="key0">-2.24393,0.94806,-2.78715</data>
    </node>
    <node id="n3">
      <data key="key0">1.39486,2.75551,-3.1367</data>
    </node>
    <node id="n4">
      <data key="key0">3.09266,0.738158,0.701538</data>
    </node>
    <edge id="e0" source="n1" target="n3">
      <data key="key1">0</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="e1" source="n4" target="n0">
      <data key="key1">0</data>
    </edge>
  </graph>
</graphml>
```

### Full Listing

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4124ad32d51b4cc6)**

```
#include <boost/graph/graphml.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/transform_value_property_map.hpp>

struct VertexProperties {
    std::vector<double> joint_angles{0, 0, 0};
};
struct EdgeProperties {
    double weight;
};

using Graph  = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS,
                                    VertexProperties, EdgeProperties>;
using Vertex = Graph::vertex_descriptor;
using Edge   = Graph::edge_descriptor;

template <typename Prop> struct JA {
    Prop inner;
    JA(Prop map) : inner(map) { }

    // traits
    using value_type = std::string;
    using reference  = std::string;
    using key_type   = typename boost::property_traits<Prop>::key_type;
    using category   = boost::read_write_property_map_tag;

    friend std::string get(JA map, key_type const& key) {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        for (auto sep = ""; auto el : get(map.inner, key))
            oss << std::exchange(sep, ",") << el;
        return oss.str();
    }
    friend void put(JA map, key_type const& key, value_type const& value) {
        auto& v = get(map.inner, key);
        v.clear();

        std::istringstream iss(value);
        while (iss >> v.emplace_back())
            if (char comma{}; !(iss >> comma) || comma != ',')
                break;
    }
};

struct BoostGraph {
    Graph graph;

    auto properties() {
        boost::dynamic_properties dp;
        dp.property("Joint_Angles", JA{get(&VertexProperties::joint_angles, graph)});
        dp.property("edge_weight", get(&EdgeProperties::weight, graph));
        return dp;
    }

    void printGraphML(std::ostream& out) {
        write_graphml(out, graph, properties());
    }

    void readGraphGraphML(std::istream& file) {
        auto dp = properties();
        read_graphml(file, graph, dp);
    }
};

#include <boost/graph/random.hpp>
#include <random>

int main() {
    std::stringstream file; // fake file in memory
    {
        BoostGraph g;
        std::mt19937 prng{42};
        generate_random_graph(g.graph, 5, 2, prng);

        for (auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g.graph)))
            for (auto& angle : g.graph[v].joint_angles)
                angle = std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(-M_PI, +M_PI)(prng);

        g.printGraphML(file);
    }

    {
        BoostGraph roundtrip;
        roundtrip.readGraphGraphML(file);
        roundtrip.printGraphML(std::cout);
    }
}
```